# Discrete Math Understanding a proof involving the definition of divisibility

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility, proof-explanation

In this first course on discrete mathematics, the instructor provided this following solution to a question. The question was asked us to prove the following (the solution is provided as well):
[image: Proof]

My question is where did the following expressions come from. It seems to be substitution, but I am not sure from where:

$a=2(2a+b)-(3a+2b)$

and

$b=2(3a+2b)-3(2a+b)$

Note: I have an understanding that $a|b$ can be written in the form $b=qa$, where $a,b,q$ are integers.

Edit: Please consider this is a first year course on discrete math, and I have no prior knowledge of linear algebra, etc.

Comment: If you don't understand why the two expressions are true, then just work out the algebra and simplify things. If you're looking for *why* one would think of these: You want $a$ and all you have is $(2a + b)$ and $(3a + 2b)$. A few minutes of playing around with algebra will lead you to this representation.

Comment: "A few minutes of playing around with algebra will lead you to this representation." This means you need to get a pencil and paper and spend five minutes trying different combinations of these things to see what works.

Comment: Of course, we could describe the process using the language of linear algebra and [gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).  The idea is that we want to use $(2a+b)$ and $(3a+2b)$ because we know things about them in relation to $d$.  We want to combine them in a linear combination to cancel the $b$'s.  We have one $b$ in the first piece and two $b$'s in the second piece.  Twice the first minus the second will accomplish that.  We could also have done four times the first minus twice the second, or some other combination that works, but we want it also to $=a$

Comment: @JMoravitz Considering you have experience in discrete mathematics, and considering that I only have knowledge of grade 12 math and simple definitions that have come from this introductory discrete mathematics course, is there a way to solve this using just the definition of divisibility that I have posted in the Note of my original text?

Comment: Gaussian elimination is taught in highschool algebra-precalculus as the "substitution" and "cancelling" methods to solving systems of linear equations.  Regardless, it doesn't need to be formalized in order to be able to be used.  Think of it like a puzzle, like figuring out how to move a knight on a chess board up exactly one space after a number of moves.  Even that problem can be formalized and a general method to solving it without fail can be taught, but with a little bit of intuition and trial and error one can accomplish it with no theoretical knowledge needed.

Comment: Another possible solution is using the euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @SajSeesSound: The short description is "solve for $a$ and $b$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this interpretation of the calculation will help. We know that $d$ divides $3a+2b$. Thus
$$3a+2b=ds\tag{1}$$
for some integer $s$. Similarly, 
$$2a+b=dt\tag{2}$$ 
for some integer $t$.  We have two equations in $a$ and $b$. **Eliminate** $b$ by multiplying the second equation through by $2$, and "subtracting" the first equation. We get
$$a=(2)(2a+b)-(3a+2b)=2dt-ds=d(2t-s),$$
and now it is clear that $d\mid a$.

Answer (score 3):

You want to solve the equation $a=(2a+b)x+(3a+2b)y$.  Comparing coefficients of $a$ and $b$ on both sides you get $2x+3y=1$ and $x+2y=0$ (right?  because the left hand side is $1\cdot a+0\cdot b$).  You can then solve this system of equations simultaneously for $x$ and $y$ to get $x=2$, $y=-3$.  Then do the same for the other equation $b=(2a+b)x+(3a+2b)y$ to get $x=-3$, $y=2$.

Answer (score 2):

It's not substitution.  It's just an identity:

$a = 4a - 3a$

$= 4a - 3a + 2b - 2b$

$= (4a + 2b) - (3a + 2b)$

$= 2(2a + b) - (3a + 2b)$.

and $b = 2(3a + 2b) - 3(2a - b)$ is don't similarly.

Then they used substitution.

A natural question to ask would be how in heck could they just stumble on the right manipulation that would work.

Well, what we could have done when we had $3a + 2b = sd$ and $2a + b = td$ we could have tried to solve directly for $a$ and $b$.  It's basic two equations, two unknowns.

$3a + 2b = sd$

$2a + b = td$

$4a + 2b = 2td$

$(4a + 2b) - (3a + 2b) = 2td - sd$

$a = d(2t-s)$

====

$6a + 4b = 2sd$

$6a + 3b = 3td$

$(6a + 4b) - (6a + 3b) = 2sd - 3td$

$b = d(2s - 3t)$

And from that they probably worked backwards.  Although to be honest I'm not sure why.  Solving directly is just as illuminating and takes out the "well, that was lucky!" factor.

=====

Actually I'd have done this a lot more straightforwardly.

Lemma:  $d|n$ and $d|m$ then $d|n \pm m$ or more generally $d|kn + lm$ for all $k,l$.

Proof:$d|n \implies n = sd$ and $d|m \implies m = td$ for some $s,t$.  Then $n \pm m = sd \pm td = d(s \pm t)$ so $d|n \pm m$.  Likewise $kn + lm = ksd + ltd = d(ks + lt)$ so $d|kn + lm$.

Then... we just do it:

$d|3a + 2b$ and $d|2a + b$ so $d|(3a + 2b)-(2a+b)$ so $d|a + b$ so $d|(2a + b) - (a+b)$ so $d|a$ so $d|(a+b) - a$ so $d|b$.

Answer (score 1):

Sums and differences of multiples of $d$ are again multiples of $d$. So if we know that $3a+2b$ and $2a+b$ are multiples of $d$ then so is their sum $(3a+2b)+(2a+b)=5a+3b$ and their difference $(3a+2b)-(2a+b)=a+b$. Again, if $2a+b$ and - as we now know - $a+b$ are multiples of $d$, then so is their difference $(2a+b)-(a+b)=a$, and after this also the difference $(a+b)-a=b$.

More systematically, any combination $u(3a+2b)+v(2a+b)$ with integers $u,v$ is a multiple of $d$. As  $u(3a+2b)+v(2a+b)=(3u+2v)a+(2u+v)b$ and we want to have only $a$, we should look at the case where the coefficient before $b$ is zero, i.e., $2u+v=0$ or $v=-2u$. Substituting this into the coefficient of $a$, we find $(3u+2(-2u))a=-ua$; hence by letting $u=-1$ (and then $v=2$), we find that $a$ is a multiple of $d$.